# \lstinputlisting with R problem

Tags: lyx, r

I'm trying to include my R code in a Lyx document but get the following error when trying to convert to PDF:

```
 \lstinputlisting{MonteCarlo.R}
                                     ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

My code looks as follows:

```
\lstset{ %
language = R, 
numbers=left,  
numbersep=10pt,  
tabsize=4,  
breaklines=true, 
title=\lstname 
}
\lstinputlisting{MonteCarlo.R}
```

But files are placed in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but without more information about your document we cannot help. This works fine as pure LaTeX

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{txtt}
\begin{document}
\lstset{ %
language = R, 
numbers=left,  
numbersep=10pt,  
tabsize=4,  
breaklines=true, 
title=\lstname 
}
\lstinputlisting{MonteCarlo.R}

\end{document}
```

I `MonteCarlo.R` I have

```
a <- rep(0,200)
for(n in 1:200) {
a[n] <- maxlike(rnorm(n,1,1))
}
```

Didn't even know there now was an `R` language definition for `listings`, guess I'd better update my `SASnRdisplay` package.